# PHP Object Inheritance - private vs protected parent method returns different result

Tags: php, oop, inheritance

I may just not have a good enough handle on PHP's object handling to understand what's going wrong here, but a snippet of code I have returns results I did not expect and I'm hoping somebody in this crowd can give me some insight into what's happening.  Here is the code:

```
class Page
{
    public function getTitle() {
        echo $this->_title();
    }

    private function _title() {
        return "Page Title\n";
    }
}

class Title extends Page
{
    protected function _title() {
        return "Title Title\n";
    }
}

$title = new Title();
$title->getTitle();
```

What I was expecting was that getTitle would be inherited by the Title class and when calling `$this->getTitle()` would return it's own method.  If you change the `_title()` method in the parent Page class to protected instead of private, it will do so.  But when the parent's method is private it gets called instead.

Is this expected behavior in object inheritance or some weird issue with PHP?  Can anyone explain the (il?)logic of this happening? Much appreciated.

Comment: Actually, I feel they should make PHP spit a fatal error instead of simply calling the private method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you copy `Page::getTitle()`'s content to `Title::getTitle()` you will get what you intended, which means the `$this` in `Page::getTitle()` always looks in itself for a possible match first and since that is private it does not look any further.

As you mentioned, you would have to declare `Page::_title()` as protected as well, in order for it to be overridden.

Comment: Sorry for the sloppy first answer, this is probably more of a discussion than an explanation as to "why" it's like that. I'm afraid I can't relate to if it's expected or not compared to other languages but I think it is a bad smell to use both private & protected methods, with the otherwise same method signature, in descending classes.

Comment: Thanks. I happened on this by accident in trying to debug another problem so they were originally both set to protected. Since the actual object loaded is Title and not Page, I would expect Page to look in itself for a method first and not it's parent, since the getTitle should be an inherited copy.  That's why I found it confusing.

Comment: @James: I can see how that bug was frustrating :) I guess your expectation (in the comment above) is wrong which is the answer to your question. I still haven't found a term for it though.

Answer (score 3):

This would also happen in Java and other OO languages.

_title() is a private function in the super class and therefore outside OO inheritence. _title() in the child class does not override the parent function of the same name.

You are making a call to the super class function getTitle() and therefore it will look for _title() in the super class first.

PHP does not support overloading directly (i.e. several functions called getTitle() with different method signatures), only indirectly through optional arguments.

Answer (score 1):

To add to Kevin S answer (which is not entirely correct) as per stated at [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php#107232): public and protected methods will be overloaded, private methods won't.

Be careful though when mixing protected and public scopes:

```
class A
{
    protected function a(){ echo "a"; }
}

class B extends A
{
    public function a(){ echo "b"; }
}
```

won't produce error on compiling, but trying to do:

```
$b = new B;
$b->a();
```

will, as "a" method will use class A scope first (per inheritance).

On the other hand:

```
class A
{
    public function a(){ echo "a"; }
}

class B extends A
{
    protected function a(){ echo "b"; }
}
```

will nicely produce fatal error on compile.

Also - PHP has different model of method calling, than for example Java/C. While in C you could differentiate methods dependant upon the arguments passed, in PHP it's not possible thanks to non explicit type definitions.